# Need to correct Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a little help with the following query. I need to find:

> Average number of people per semester of each campus

My table structure is:

- table name - registration
- columns

  - student_id
  - campus
  - year
  - batch
  - semester

and with the help of `campus`, `year`, `semester` and `batch` I can identify each unique semester. More over my `student_id` repeats itself in the db.

I did following but it won't help. So I need some help.

```
SELECT semester,year,campus
  FROM regestration
  GROUP BY  semester, year, campus
  ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Comment: It's spelled "registration"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT year,campus, AVG(CountOfStudents)
FROM
(
  SELECT semester,year,campus, count(*) as CountOfStudents
  FROM regestration
  GROUP BY  semester, year, campus
) t
GROUP BY  year, campus
```

Comment: The outer select will return the inner select's result, as the outer group-by will not actually group anything.

Comment: @pointy's answer may be an improvement depending on how the data is stored in regestration.  However, might even need `COUNT(DISTINCT student_id)` in place of `COUNT(*)`.  Can there be multiple entries per student in the regestration table for a given semester,year,campus?

Comment: @zmbq: thanks. I edited my answer to better conform to the question.  Got rid of semester in outer group by, since indicates they want students per campus (probably per year).

Comment: yes there can be multiple entries per student in regestration table

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of students in each campus each semester you need to add COUNT(*) to your query:

```
SELECT semester, year, campus, COUNT(*) as students
    FROM registration
    GROUP BY semester, year, campus
```

I don't know what average you want here, though.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select avg(students), campus from (
  select count(student_id) students, campus from registration
   group by semester, year, campus
) group by campus
```

Comment: it's good and worked after i added year attribute in the group by with campus. Thanks